# How to find some specific term in Perl Document?

Tags: perl

I want to look the definition of `ARGV,$ARGV,@ARGV`, so I use perldoc to find it. Since it's not a sub nor a module ,`perldoc -f` or `perldoc module` would not help.

I asked someone and he told me to look at `perldoc perlvar`,and I found ARGV section.

My question is how to find some general term in Perl Document? Or how to find out that ARGV is in `perlvar` ? Some universal search tool to do this?

Comment: Why is it strange that you'd look for a documentation on a perl variable in "perldoc perlvar"? It's a theme: perlre, perlfunc, perlop, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found after a brief search of `perldoc --help`:

```
....
-v   Search predefined Perl variables
```

So, basically:

```
$ perldoc -v @ARGV

@ARGV   The array @ARGV contains the command-line arguments intended
        for the script.  $#ARGV is generally the number of arguments
        minus one, because $ARGV[0] is the first argument, not the
        program's command name itself.  See $0 for the command name.
```

Though you'll have to be creative when looking up scalars to avoid shell interpolation:

```
perldoc -f '$ARGV'
```

Answer (score 1):

*perldoc* is not the solution; it’s the problem.  The solution is either:

```
$ cd src/perl/pod
$ grep foo *.pod
```

or

```
$ cd src/perl/pod
$ pod2text `grep -l foo *.pod` | more
```

Accept no substitutes.

Comment: In case `src/perl/pod` is not where Perl docs are installed on your system, you can find the right directory with `perldoc -l perl`.

Comment: Accept this substitute: https://metacpan.org/module/App::perlzonji - Less complicated command-lines, more DWIM.

Comment: @daxim No-one who finds `grep` ‘a complicated command-line’ is going to be successful as a Perl programmer. I regularly grep for `^=.*foo` in all the pods’ pod-directives, or for `^[^=\s].*foo` for pod body text, or for `^\s.*foo` in pod code. Until constructing mind-numbingly trivial pattern matches like these becomes completely reflexive and automatic, any would-be Perl programmer is going to be utterly miserable. You may toss them the occasional fish now&then, but they will never get the hang of the power of proper searching and tool combinations. They'll be forever hungry — and begging.

Comment: @daxim No one cares about throwing people prepackaged tinned fish that they don’t even have handy when it is infinitely better to teach them how to fish using the tackle that they already have.  To ignore the stength of the Unix philosophy and of Perl itself is foolish and mean-spirited. You create a dependent class of helpless mendicants instead of self-empowering tool-users able to devise new applications that you never dreamt of. If we needed more of those, we’d all run Winblows.

Comment: If `perldoc` is the problem, shouldn't the solution be `patch perldoc`?  It seems like full text search of all of the pods is a feature `perldoc` is missing.

Comment: @EricStrom Sorry, I wouldn’t know: I’m not a Windows user/victim.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative: Google using

```
site:perldoc.perl.org TERM
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I started reading the perl documentation with `perldoc perl`.  It has a brief overview of all the perl docs (except modules) present in your version of perl.  For a bit more detail, you'll notice that one of the docs in the "Overview" section is "perltoc", so a bit of dry reading in `perldoc perltoc` would likely answer your question.